# uitabelview in uipopoverview

Tags: iphone, ios6, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

Can any one please give me reference or tutorial for how to include uitabelview in uipopopover view Controlelr with detail view controller,Please do the needfully, Thanks in advance

Update:

```
 - (IBAction) useCameraRoll: (id)sender
 {

if([self.popoverController isPopoverVisible])
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    return;
 }
 //build our custom popover view
 UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
 UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 102)];
 popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

 UITableView *tblViewMenu = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 102)];
 tblViewMenu.delegate = self;
 tblViewMenu.dataSource = self;
 tblViewMenu.rowHeight = 32;
 [popoverView addSubview:tblViewMenu];
 popoverContent.view = popoverView;
 popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(140, 102);
 self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                          initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
 //present the popover view non-modal with a
 //refrence to the toolbar button which was pressed
 [self.popoverController  presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 29)
                                         inView:gal   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to google your Query before posting here. 
You can find one tutorial here
http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.in/2010/11/how-to-insert-uitableview-in.html

Comment: i did but i want popover with detail view controller,even in your link the same question askd??

Comment: i want to show tabelview in popoverview, while tryin your refrence link it showing the following error  `'-[Viewipad6 tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71b16d0'
erminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: you need to add these uitableview delegate methods in your vieecontroller